Using rust features as a build flag
I'm trying to use the features of a Cargo.toml file to conditionally set a property at build time. I do this so that I can have some slight differences for the build intended for integration testing.
#[cfg(feature = "inttest")]
const INFO_BYTES_SIZE: u32 = 28500;

#[cfg(not(feature = "inttest"))]
const INFO_BYTES_SIZE: u32 = 2000;

pretty simple right? If the inttest feature is enabled then MAX_SWAP_INFO_BYTES_SIZE becomes 28500.
all the packages .toml files have the same feature and list the dependency like so

[features]
default = []  # Empty default features
inttest = []

[dependencies]
common_code = { path = "../common", features = []}

when i build cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --target-dir $1/target --release --locked --features inttest -p $1
the feature doesn't get turned on and i still see the INFO_BYTES_SIZE as 2000.
Any ideas on why?
if i set the feature like so
common_code = { path = "../common", features = ["inttest"]}

then it does work, but now production has the wrong value and it's always set to 28500

Please [edit] your question to clarify where the snippets live, you seem to have at least two different crates playing a role here. Please include a [mre] with all necessary files.

Features are defined per-crate. Here, both package and common_code have a feature named inttest, but they are not the same feature; they just happen to be named the same. Enabling package/inttest will not automatically enable common_code/inttest.
If you want enabling package/inttest to also enable common_code/inttest, you need to explicitly state the feature dependency:
[features]
default = []
inttest = ["common_code/inttest"]

[dependencies]
common_code = { path = "../common" }

See The Cargo Book.
